# I saved an image in local database. whenever i try to open using glide. i get the following log

Tags: android, android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89xLG.png)

fail to get the list and getting null pointer exception.

whenever i add the product into cart then it proceed into cart but image is not loaded and getting error of null pointer exception

```
class CartFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentCartBinding
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        binding = FragmentCartBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        val preference = requireContext().getSharedPreferences("info", AppCompatActivity.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val editor = preference.edit()
        editor.putBoolean("isCart",false)
        editor.apply()

        val dao = AppDatabase.getInstance(requireContext()).productDao()
        dao.getAllProducts().observe(requireActivity()){
            binding.cartRecycler.adapter = CartAdapter(requireContext(),it)

            totalCost(it)
        }

        return binding.root
    }

    private fun totalCost(data: List<ProductModel>) {
        var total = "0"
        for (item in data){
            total += item.productSp!!.toString()

        }
        binding.textView12.text = "Total item in cart is ${data.size}"
        binding.textView13.text = "Total Cost $total"

        binding.checkout.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(context, AddressActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("totalCost",total)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: put your local database code

Comment: hey i added some code please check

Comment: bro i want your image insert code..

Comment: Glide.with(context).load(list[position].productImage).into(holder.binding.imageView4)

Comment: Why do you use a database for storing images instead of keeping in the database path to image file?

Comment: can you please correct me in code where i am going wrong